# How can I verify that my string ends with a particular data?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have a String

```
String s = "a/b/c/d/data/info";
```

I need to find is `info` exist. And `info` should follow right after `data`. How can I verify that my string ends with a particular data (`info`)?

*UPD*

I need to find and retrieve string which follows `.../data/{thisString}`

Comment: You could try using split("/") which should return a `String[]` that you can iterate through and check if ends with `info` and then access it whenever you need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String repl = "a/b/c/d/data/info".replaceFirst("^.*?data/([^/]+)$", "$1");
//=> info
```

Comment: But if I have `/asdasd/asd/data/someOtherString`? I cant retrieve `someOtherString`.

Comment: In that case you will get `someOtherString` returned from above.

Comment: [Coding Horror:](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." ;-)

Comment: @barbara: Are you sure you checked updated code here?

Comment: I think the problem is that you trying to set `info`. But this is actually variable data.

Comment: Then I think you haven't looked at updated code. I have `replaceFirst("^.*?data/([^/]+)$", "$1");` and it has no `"info"` string literal in it.

Comment: No , I'm repeating myself 3rd time. Check my latest code. It should be: **`String userId = s.replaceFirst("^.*?data/([^/]+)$", "$1");`**

Answer (score 2):

```
s.endsWith( "data/info" )
```

is `true`.

EDIT:
OK, so "info" is just your stand-in for any string.  You could check for the "data/" with `indexOf` and then use `substring` to get just the "info" part.

```
  String s = "a/b/c/data/info";
  String info = null;
  if( s.indexOf( "data/" ) >= 0 ) {
     info = s.substring( s.indexOf( "data/" ) + "data/".length() );
  }
  System.out.println( info );
```

Comment: Actually I need to get `info`. I mean I need to get the string which is after `data/`.

Comment: What do you meant "get" info?  It's a constant string.

Comment: "a/b/c/data/John" > "John"

Answer (score 0):

Username after data/:

```
String s = "a/b/c/d/data/info";

System.out.println(s.split("data/")[1]);
```

outputs:

```
info
```